# Confusing C# method definition

Tags: c#, methods, enums, polymorphism

I'm currently working through the "[A C# Crash Course](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/c-sharp-tutorials)" by RB Whitaker. I'm on the [Polymorphism](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/c-sharp-abstract-classes) chapter at the moment and I'm stuck on this part:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Inheritance
{
    public enum MoveDirection { None, Left, Right, Up, Down };

    class Player
    {
        public virtual MoveDirection MakeMove()
        {
            return MoveDirection.Left;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand everything up to:

```
public virtual MoveDirection MakeMove()
```

The use of `public virtual` and `MakeMove()` makes sense. However, I don't understand why the enumeration (`MoveDirection`) is placed in front of the method `MakeMove()`. I suspect it has something to do with where this part of the tutorial:

> We define our MakeMove() method, which uses the enumeration we created as a parameter, and add in the virtual keyword.

Does this mean that in order to use an enumeration as a parameter for a method it should be placed before the method, rather than in between the round brackets?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's not a parameter, it's the type of the returned value/reference.

Comment: No it just means that the method returns `MoveDirection` value, in the same way as `public virtual int foo()` would mean that `foo` returns an `int`. I think the description the author gave is incorrect and should read *"the enumeration we created as a return value"*

Comment: Seems you should switch to another tutorial ;0

Answer (score 4):

`MoveDirection` is before `MakeMove()` because it is the type returned by that method. In C#, you need to specify the type returned by a method by putting it in front of the method name. If the method doesn't return anything, you need to put `void` keyword.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173114.aspx):

> Methods can return a value to the caller. If the return type, **the type listed before the method name**, is not void, the method can return the value by using the return keyword. A statement with the return keyword followed by a value that matches the return type will return that value to the method caller. The return keyword also stops the execution of the method. If the return type is void, a return statement without a value is still useful to stop the execution of the method. Without the return keyword, the method will stop executing when it reaches the end of the code block. Methods with a non-void return type are required to use the return keyword to return a value.

---

What you put between brackets after the method name, are parameters of the method:

> The method definition specifies the names and types of any parameters that are required.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thanks a lot for the response.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that in order to use an enumeration as a parameter for
>   a method it should be placed before the method, rather than in between
>   the round brackets?

Not.It can be place in any accesable from this method place.It recommended place Enum in separated file.

For Example we can change class like this:

In first file:

```
namespace Inheritance
{
    class Player
    {
        public virtual MoveDirection MakeMove()
        {
            return MoveDirection.Left;
        }
    }
}
```

In other file

```
namespace Inheritance
{
    public enum MoveDirection { None, Left, Right, Up, Down };
}
```